# Open Source Search UI projects that can be consume REST services

Tags: python, api, search, search-engine, django-haystack

I'm trying to find a solution to my current problem. Let me explain: I need to find a Search UI that can consume a REST service of my choice and be highly configurable. I've searched the web and found Blacklight Search UI (written in Ruby) for Solr. I've also looked at Haystack (for django) which seems to be more promissing because somewhere in the docs i found out that you can link Haystack to your custom search engine. Out of the box Haystack supports Solr, Xapian and 2 others which i can't remember now.

What i'm trying to find is a UI written in Java, PHP(last resort!) or Python that will allow me to specify the endpoints for my APIs and with a few configurations (i'm not expecting it to run out of the box) it should be able to query the APIs and return results.

If that is not possible then could somebody suggest me something that gets close to what I described and allows me to write my own backend code that will link to the APIs ? A Haystack example will also do...

Thanks

Comment: What did you use finally?

Answer (score 1):

I'm interested in this topic as well. I know about the [SESAT](http://sesat.no/) framework supporting FAST, Solr, Yahoo!, generic XML and more, but it is old and not well maintained, and also tries to do much more than a simple front-end.

You also have [AJAX-Solr](http://evolvingweb.github.com/ajax-solr/) which obviously only supports Solr.

I have forwarded your question on Twitter, hope others will fill in as well.